# Alamofire Request call with: Parameters, Headers and Body not working

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift5

I have two questions with regards to the Alamofire code below.

My JSON fails if I remove the ?action=heartbeat at the end of the URL even though I have action = heartbeat in the parameters, why?

How do I add my JSON data/body in the AF.request code below?

```
let urlString   = "https://intelipos.dynalias.net/ioc/rest.asp?action=heartbeat"
let parameters  = ["action":"heartbeat"]
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application/json"]

AF.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
  switch response.result {
  case .success:
    print("Validation Successful")
  case let .failure(error):
    print(error)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question One

You need to encode as a querystring

```swift
let urlString   = "https://intelipos.dynalias.net/ioc/rest.asp"
let parameters  = ["action":"heartbeat"]
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application/json"]

AF.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  URLEncoding.queryString, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
  switch response.result {
  case .success:
    print("Validation Successful")
  case let .failure(error):
    print(error)
  }
}
```

> Question Two

You have to prepare an encodable model and pass it in `parameters` argument and set encoding to `JSONEncoding.default`

Refer this article: https://medium.com/whoknows-swift/swift-4-decodable-encodable-3085305a9618

Comment: Thanks, that answers question one. How do I add the body to that AF.request call?
eg: {“Command” : ”xxxx”, “Data” : “base64(xdata)”,”Signature” : ””}

Comment: You have to prepare an encodable model and pass it in `parameters` argument and set encoding to `JSONEncoding.default`

Comment: Thanks Suresh, I do understand I need to create a struct, I'm unsure where to pass it but you say in my parameters. If my struct is JSONdata do I simply change the above parameters variable to: let parameters  = ["action":"heartbeat", "body":"JSONdata"] ?

Comment: Thats not a proper way. I suggest you to know more about encoding and sending JSON data from multiple models.

Comment: Where should I start? Do you have a link or two for me?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that.

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "request_token" : LoginVC.REQUEST_TOKEN
        ]


        Alamofire.request("https://api.com"
, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default , headers: nil)
```

Comment: Ok, based on this and the comment from Suresh I understand I need to build that query string to my JSON. Tnx