# Pass string along with arrays but string read as a null in swift with Alamofire

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, alamofire

I Pass the string also one param along with array at API hitting time using Alamofire.

But response time my string read as a nill please anyone suggest to me.

**These are my parameters**

```
let apiurl = "https://www.furnitureinfashion.net/FIF-APP/app_array_cart.php?"

let params:[String:Any] = ["customer_id":"152698",
                                   "product_id":["27372","31872"],
                                   "qty":["3","4"],
                                   "option":["1202",""]]
```

**find my API hitting code as following**

```
Alamofire.request(apiurl, method:.get, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
   if response.result.value != nil{
     print(response)
   }else{
     print(response.result.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
   }
}
```

I get a response like this:

```
SUCCESS: {
    Message = "Customer id missing";
    cusid = "<null>";
    status = "Not ok";
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58855389/9136962

Comment: Check the server param what actually the customerId param is. Is it `cusid` or `customer_id` ?

Comment: no no correct only

Comment: What actually the request will be? Is it POST request or GET request? Seems like it will be POST request not GET.

Comment: it is GET only from Backend.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct way only based on the backend person required meant we send the format either it is decoded or encode

This is backend issue.

```
Alamofire.request(apiurl, method:.get, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
   if response.result.value != nil{
     print(response)
   }else{
     print(response.result.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
   }
}
```